# Как добавить максимальный таумаут?

Tags: linux, bash, curl

Скачиваю радио поток с сайта, бывает так что сутки сайт не доступен и мой `curl` скрипт накрывается медным тазом. Я пробовал добавить несколько параметров, но сути не меняет.

```
#!/bin/bash
u=$1
[ -n "$u" ] || { echo "using"; exit 1; }
n=0
p="part"
s=100*1024*1024
while true; do
  printf -v f "%s%0.3d" $p $n
  echo -n "download $f"
  if ! curl --retry 100000000 --max-time 10000000  -s -f -r $((n*s))-$(((n+1)*s-1)) "$u" > "$f"; then exit $?; fi
  echo ". ready. next num: $((++n))"
  echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
done
```

Comment: Вам надо пересмотреть подход к решению задачи. (Смотря на код, кажется вы уже постили где-то вопрос с этим скриптом, да так и не усвоили ответов)